# How can I use OVER and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, sql-order-by, window-functions

I can't understand this code's bug.

**CODE:**

```
SELECT
    CariID, HesapID, BTrh, BCinsiID, BNo, Acklm, VdTrh, mTrh, BorcT, AlacakT, 
    SUM(BorcT) OVER (PARTITION BY CariID, HesapID ORDER BY BTrh, BNo, mTrh) AS TopBorcT, 
    SUM(AlacakT) OVER (PARTITION BY CariID, HesapID ORDER BY BTrh, BNo, mTrh ) AS TopAlacakT
FROM
    tCariH
```

**ERROR:**

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? I believe that the syntax you've shown only works on 2012 (and probably later versions, which don't as yet exist)

Answer (score 2):

With an aggregate function like `SUM`, [you don't use `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) - you only need to use the `PARTITION` function.  The `ORDER` is used for ranking functions:

> Depending on the ranking, aggregate, or analytic function used with the OVER clause, `<ORDER BY clause>` and/or the `<ROWS and RANGE clause>` may not be supported.

Just modify to remove the `ORDER` in both your aggregates and you should be fine.

Comment: You *can* use an ORDER BY with sum() or avg(). It will then create a "running" sum (or average) up to the "current row". Unlesse Oracle and PostgreSQL SQL Server has not supported that until now. Only with the brand new SQL Server 2012 this is supported

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Thanks for the info, I didn't realize it changed in 2012

Comment: ID      AccountID       Quantity
1          1               10           Sum = 10
2          1               5                = 10 + 5 = 15
3          1               2                = 10 + 5 + 2 = 17
4          2               7                = 7
5          2               3                = 7 + 3 = 10  

SELECT ID, AccountID, Quantity, 
       SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ) AS TopBorcT, 
FROM tCariH

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is not supported in SQL Server 2008, but it is support in SQL Server 2012

[How to use partition by and order by in over function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541355/how-to-use-partition-by-and-order-by-in-over-function)

Try this tool and you can see why: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5303f/1

Answer (score 0):

```
ID      AccountID       Quantity
1          1               10           Sum = 10
2          1               5                = 10 + 5 = 15
3          1               2                = 10 + 5 + 2 = 17
4          2               7                = 7
5          2               3                = 7 + 3 = 10  

SELECT ID, AccountID, Quantity, 
       SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ) AS TopBorcT, 
FROM tCariH
```