# Cumulative count with group by and case when

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cumulative-sum

I have been searching for this and trying to make this code work for a week now.

My data set `tbSubscriptions` has the columns:

```
Subscription_Date (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss)  
Subscription_Id (char 6)  
Subscription_Type (char 1)
```

To retrieve the number of subscriptions per week I use:

```
select   
   datepart(wk,Subscription_Date) as WeekNo,   
   sum(case when Subscription_Type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalSubcriptions  
from tbSubscriptions  
group by datepart(wk,Subscription_Date)  
order by 1
```

This query returns:

```
WeekNo  |Total Subscriptions  
21      |12  
22      |13  
23      |8  
24      |18
```

What I want is a Query that returns:

```
WeekNo  |CumulativeSubscriptions  
21      |12  
22      |25 (=12+13)  
23      |33 (=25+8)  
24      |51 (=33+18)
```

Here is a sample data set creation script:

```
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tbSubscriptions') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE tbSubscriptions
GO
CREATE TABLE tbSubscriptions (Subscription_Id INT, Subscription_Date datetime, Subscription_Type INT)
GO 
INSERT INTO tbSubscriptions (Subscription_Id, Subscription_Date, Subscription_Type) 
VALUES
(1, convert(datetime,'01-08-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(2, convert(datetime,'15-08-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(3, convert(datetime,'01-09-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(4, convert(datetime,'09-09-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(5, convert(datetime,'18-09-16 00:00:00 AM',5),0), 
(6, convert(datetime,'15-10-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(7, convert(datetime,'22-10-16 00:00:00 AM',5),0), 
(8, convert(datetime,'23-10-16 00:00:00 AM',5),0), 
(9, convert(datetime,'01-11-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(10, convert(datetime,'02-11-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(11, convert(datetime,'14-11-16 00:00:00 AM',5),0), 
(12, convert(datetime,'01-12-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(13, convert(datetime,'02-12-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(14, convert(datetime,'05-12-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(15, convert(datetime,'09-12-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(16, convert(datetime,'10-12-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(17, convert(datetime,'11-12-16 00:00:00 AM',5),1), 
(18, convert(datetime,'19-12-16 00:00:00 AM',5),0),
(19, convert(datetime,'25-12-16 00:00:00 AM',5),0),
(20, convert(datetime,'29-12-16 00:00:00 AM',5),0);
GO
```

I have tried both methods for cumulative sum (Window Functions and Self Joins), but couldn't get to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Paulo.

Comment: IT WORKED WITH

"SELECT 
datepart(wk,Subscription_Date), 
(
 SELECT Count(Subscription_Id) 
 FROM tbSubscriptions t2 
 WHERE datepart(wk,t2.Subscription_Date)<=datepart(wk,t1.Subscription_Date) and
t2.Subscription_Type= 1
) AS running_total
FROM tbSubscriptions t1
WHERE 
 t1.Subscription_Type= 1
GROUP BY datepart(wk,t1.Subscription_Date)
ORDER BY datepart(wk,t1.Subscription_Date)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
with cte as(
    select   
        datepart(wk,Subscription_Date) as WeekNo,   
        sum(case when Subscription_Type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalSubcriptions
    from tbSubscriptions  
    group by datepart(wk,Subscription_Date)  
)
select
    c.Weekno,
    t.TotalSubcriptions
from cte c
cross apply(
    select sum(TotalSubcriptions) as TotalSubcriptions
    from cte
    where WeekNo <= c.WeekNo
) t
order by WeekNo
```

If you're using SQL Server 2012 and above, you can use the `SUM OVER` function:

```
with cte as(
    select   
       datepart(wk,Subscription_Date) as WeekNo,   
       sum(case when Subscription_Type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalSubcriptions  
    from tbSubscriptions  
    group by datepart(wk,Subscription_Date)  
)
select
    Weekno,
    sum(TotalSubcriptions) over(order by WeekNo) as CumulativeSubscriptions
from cte
order by WeekNo
```

Comment: Thanks but Im running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and it doesnt seem to support running agregates with OVER (ORDER BY...) 

More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541355/how-to-use-partition-by-and-order-by-in-over-function

Any thoughts?

Comment: @JoãoAlqueres Try the `CROSS APPLY` solution.

Comment: Thanks Felix ! It worked with another method by @KthProg at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server

Thank you so much anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `sum` window function.

```
select distinct 
   datepart(wk,Subscription_Date) as WeekNo,   
   sum(case when Subscription_Type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) 
   over(partition by datepart(wk,Subscription_Date) 
        order by datepart(wk,Subscription_Date)) as TotalSubcriptions  
from tbSubscriptions  
--group by datepart(wk,Subscription_Date)  
order by 1
```

Edit: Without using window functions, you can use a correlated sub query.

```
select datepart(week,subscription_date) wk
,count(case when subscription_type=1 then 1 end) + 
(select count(case when subscription_type=1 then 1 end) 
 from tbsubscriptions t1 
 where datepart(week,t.subscription_date)>datepart(week,t1.subscription_date)) cnt
from tbsubscriptions t
group by datepart(week,subscription_date)
```

Comment: Thanks but Im running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and it doesnt seem to support running agregates with OVER (ORDER BY...) 

More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541355/how-to-use-partition-by-and-order-by-in-over-function

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server 2008 version**

```
with cte as (
   select
    datepart(year,Subscription_Date) as YearNo,
    datepart(week,Subscription_Date) as WeekNo,
    sum(case when Subscription_Type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Total
   from tbSubscriptions
   group by datepart(year,Subscription_Date), datepart(week,Subscription_Date)
)
select 
--t1.YearNo,
t1.WeekNo,
sum(t2.Total) as TotalSubcriptions
from cte t1
inner join cte t2 on (t1.YearNo*100+t1.WeekNo >= t2.YearNo*100+t2.WeekNo)
group by t1.YearNo, t1.WeekNo
order by t1.YearNo, t1.WeekNo;
```

**SQL Server 2012 version**

```
select 
--YearNo,
WeekNo,
sum(Total) over (order by YearNo, WeekNo) as TotalSubcriptions
from (
   select
    datepart(year,Subscription_Date) as YearNo, 
    datepart(week,Subscription_Date) as WeekNo,
    sum(iif(Subscription_Type = 1,1,0)) as Total
   from tbSubscriptions
   group by datepart(year,Subscription_Date), datepart(week,Subscription_Date)
) q
order by YearNo, WeekNo;
```

Comment: Thanks but Im running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and it doesnt seem to support running agregates with OVER (ORDER BY...) 

More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541355/how-to-use-partition-by-and-order-by-in-over-function

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the conditional aggregation, how about putting `Subscription_Type` in the `WHERE`

```
Select Distinct 
       WeekNo            = datepart(wk,Subscription_Date)
      ,TotalSubcriptions = sum(1) over (Order By datepart(wk,Subscription_Date))
From   tbSubscriptions  
Where  Subscription_Type = 1
Order  By 1
```

> **Edit 2008 version**

```
;with cte as (
      Select WeekNo=datepart(wk,Subscription_Date)
            ,Cnt=count(*)
      From   tbSubscriptions
      Where  Subscription_Type = 1
      Group By datepart(wk,Subscription_Date)
) 
Select A.WeekNo 
      ,TotalSubcriptions = sum(B.Cnt)
 From  cte A
 Join  cte B on (A.WeekNo>=B.WeekNo)
 Group By A.WeekNo
 Order By 1
```

Returns

```
WeekNo  TotalSubcriptions
32      1
34      2
36      3
37      4
42      5
45      7
49      9
50      12
51      13
```

Comment: Thanks but Im running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and it doesnt seem to support running agregates with OVER (ORDER BY...) 

More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541355/how-to-use-partition-by-and-order-by-in-over-function

Any thoughts?

Comment: @JoãoAlqueres Fair enough.  FYI, when you tag SQL Server, it is generally assumed currently supported versions which is 2012+.   Just for for future reference, just be sure to mention 2008.