# Group following rows using only one flag

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, group-by

I have a table with a Flag column which can be true/false.
I would like to group rows and calculate average of column Val as shown in the picture below:

Source table and Desired results

[image]

Comment: you want the avg of the rows with flag = 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a derived table and windowed functions:

```
declare @t table(ID int,Val decimal(10,2),Flag bit);
insert into @t values (515,5.4,0),(516,1,1),(517,0,0),(518,0,0),(519,3,0),(520,7,0),(521,8,0),(522,2,0),(523,5,0),(524,3,1),(525,1,0),(526,2,0),(527,3,0),(528,2,0),(529,8,0),(530,9,0),(531,0,0),(532,4,1),(533,0,0),(534,2,0),(535,1,0),(536,0,0),(537,0,1),(538,1,0);

with c as
(
    select ID
            ,Val
            ,Flag
            ,sum(cast(Flag as int)) over (order by ID) as rn
    from @t
)
select cast(min(ID) as nvarchar(10)) + ' to ' + cast(max(ID) as nvarchar(10)) as IDRange
    ,avg(Val) as AverageVal
from c
group by rn
order by rn;
```

Output:

```
+------------+------------+
|  IDRange   | AverageVal |
+------------+------------+
| 515 to 515 |        5.4 |
| 516 to 523 |       3.25 |
| 524 to 531 |        3.5 |
| 532 to 536 |        1.4 |
| 537 to 538 |        0.5 |
+------------+------------+
```

---

## Update for 2008 R2 version

This utilises recursion to get your running grouping so can probably be improved upon, but will get you the results you want:

```
declare @t table(ID int,Val decimal(10,2),Flag bit);
insert into @t values (515,5.4,0),(516,1,1),(517,0,0),(518,0,0),(519,3,0),(520,7,0),(521,8,0),(522,2,0),(523,5,0),(524,3,1),(525,1,0),(526,2,0),(527,3,0),(528,2,0),(529,8,0),(530,9,0),(531,0,0),(532,4,1),(533,0,0),(534,2,0),(535,1,0),(536,0,0),(537,0,1),(538,1,0);

with t as
(
    select ID
            ,Val
            ,Flag
            ,row_number() over (order by ID) as rn
    from @t
),c as
(
    select ID
            ,Val
            ,Flag
            ,rn
            ,0 as g
    from t
    where rn = 1

    union all

    select t.ID
            ,t.Val
            ,t.Flag
            ,t.rn
            ,c.g + cast(t.Flag as int) as g
    from t
        join c
            on t.rn = c.rn+1
)
select cast(min(ID) as nvarchar(10)) + ' to ' + cast(max(ID) as nvarchar(10)) as IDRange
    ,avg(Val) as AverageVal
from c
group by g
order by g;
```

Comment: Brilliant use of `SUM()` as an analytic function +1

Comment: MS SQL 2008 R2:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: @MarkK  The `over` clause is supported [from 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) so you shouldn't have a problem with the query.  Have you copied my syntax correctly?

Comment: @iamdave I am pretty sure that I have copied it correct.
If I delete ORDER BY ID and leave empty brackets - query does not return an error.

Comment: It seems like it would work only in MS SQL Server 2012 and newer according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541355/how-to-use-partition-by-and-order-by-in-over-function)

Comment: @MarkK  Updated my answer.